# calcul elapsed time async function javascript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I would like to calcul and display in a file the elapsed time for each call response.

Promise function

```js
function callPromise(ms, promise) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
            reject(new Error(`Timeout after ${ms} ms`))
        }, ms);
        promise.then(
            (res) => {
                clearTimeout(timeoutId);
                resolve(res);
            },
            (err) => {
                clearTimeout(timeoutId);
                reject(err);
            }
        );
    })
}
```

Response call

```js
        const response = await callPromise(10, fetch(url, {
            method: request.method,
            headers: header,
            body: body
        }))
```

Answer (score 2):

With `console.time()` ?

```
console.time("Elapsed time :");
const response = await callPromise(...);
console.timeEnd("Elapsed time :"); // Will log "Elapsed time : 6.9165ms"
```

Comment: yes but I dont need that on the console but with logger.info !

Comment: And why didn't you say so in your question :/ You said "I would like to calcul and display" and that's what my answer does.

Comment: sorry my bad :( ! Post edited